# Using struct in c

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>   
struct Bar{
    int max;
    int N;
    int k[4];
    float g[4];
};


typedef struct Bar myStruct;



myStruct entr(){
    myStruct result;
    int i;

    printf("max\n");
    scanf("%d", &result.max);

    printf("N = \n");
    scanf("%d", &result.N);

    printf("\nEnter k = ");
    for(i=1; i<=4; i++) scanf("%d", &result.k[i]);

    printf("\ng = ");
    for(i=1; i<=4; i++) scanf("%f" , &result.g[i]);

    return result;
}


void main() {       
    myStruct entrs=entr();
}
```

I ran this code in linux (compile with gcc), and every time it has the following error

> "*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
>   Aborted
>   "

How can I resolve this error?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the boundary (overrun).

In your case

```
  for(i=1; i<=4; i++)
```

should be

```
  for(i=0; i<4; i++)
```

as C arrays use 0-based indexing. Otherwise, with your code, you're

- leaving the element at index 0 unused (lesser problem)
- going [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), accessing out of bound memory (bigger issue, causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).)

That said, `void main()` should be `int main(void)` for a hosted environment to be standard conforming.

Comment: this is the right response. Nothing to add, well done.